# how can i add custom prompt template on ConversationalRetrievalChain

Tags: data-science, openai-api, langchain

```
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0.8,model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k'),db.as_retriever(), memory=memory)
```

creating a chatbot for replying in a document. I want add prompt to it that it must only reply from the document and avoid making up the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add your custom prompt with the *combine_docs_chain_kwargs* parameter: `combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt}`

You can change your code as follows: `qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0.8,model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k'), db.as_retriever(), memory=memory, combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt})`

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: That sounds great - is the parameter `combine_docs_chain_kwargs` somehow also available in the JS/TS framework? I did not find anything about this in the JS/TS documentation